# How to restart python script?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to Python and I know that this might be considered as duplicate, because I have searched for solution for this problem but unfortunately nothing seems to be working for me as expected. I would like to restart script, which means to re-run running process or create separate one and kill the previous.

Currently I'm running script with `Python 3.11.2`, I have tried `os.execv(sys.executeable, ['python'] + sys.argv)` but for me this works just like `exit()`, it terminates the script and won't start it again. I have got closer by using `os.system("py "+sys.argv[0])` but here is another problem and that is it will create new process but that seems to be dependent on previous one, so I cannot call simply `exit()` afterwards to stop it like in my code.

```
import os
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process 

def run():
    print("Running tests...")


def restart():
    print("Restarting...")
    os.system("python " + sys.argv[0])
    exit()

textInput = "N"
print("Starting...")   
while textInput.startswith("N"):
    run()
    textInput = input("Restart ? (Y/N)")
    if textInput.startswith("Y"):
        restart()
```

Comment: `"python" + sys.argv` should get an error. You can't concatenate a string with a list.

Comment: If you're on an UNIX system, you could use the `os.exec*` family of functions to restart the current program.

Comment: @AKX That was their first attempt, as described in the question.

Comment: @Barmar you are right I have forgotten squared braces, it should look like this `os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)`

Comment: Better to repeat `sys.executable`  there, rather than hard-code the name, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `os.execv()` incorrectly, you can't concatenate a string and a list. You can concatenate two lists, though, so you need to wrap a list around the executable name.

```
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

You can also use `os.execl()` and spread `sys.argv` into separate arguments.

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

Transcript:

```
$ python testrestart.py 
Starting...
Running tests...
Restart ? (Y/N)Y
Restarting...
Starting...
Running tests...
Restart ? (Y/N)Y
Restarting...
Starting...
Running tests...
Restart ? (Y/N)N
Running tests...
Restart ? (Y/N)N
Running tests...
Restart ? (Y/N)Q
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but there is no change in behavior that I have described previously. Script will just terminate.

Comment: You're importing multiprocessing in your code snippet, but never use it. If the real application has multiple processes, this will just restart the current process, not all of them.

Comment: No, my application does not have multiple processes. I was exploring solutions from https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/how-to-restart-python-script-from-within-itself. I believe that author's snippet dedicated to processes should address issue that you are describing.

Comment: I just tested my code and it works.

Comment: BTW, the code repeats whether you answer Y or N. Y makes it call `restart()`, `N` makes the `while` loop repeat. I have to type something else to make it stop.

Comment: Did you enter `Y` or `y`? It's case-sensitive, so you have to enter `Y`.

Comment: I was running this in VS Code integratedTerminal, that in my case is PS, this script is working as expected in cmd. Thank you.